# JScrollPane not repaint Canvas when scrolling?

Tags: java, canvas, jscrollpane

I trying to make a game where I add a Canvas to a JScrollPane but the canvas is larger than the visible area of the JScrollPane. So when I scroll the JScrollPane to see the rest I only see the blank area even though my Canvas is continuously redrawn. Anybody can help me??

Comment: If you definitely need to use Canvas (for example, if you delegate the paint call to a native method), then use ScrollPane instead of JScrollPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing components do not work with heavyweight AWT components like Canvas. Use a JComponent or a JPanel instead of a Canvas

Comment: so there's no way to use a Canvas and JScrollPane?

Answer (score 9):

It is common JScrollPane problem. To [fix this with minimum fuss](http://andrewtill.blogspot.ru/2012/06/jscrollpane-repainting-problems.html), call the following methods on your JScrollPane:

```
scrollpane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a lightweight JPanel and 2 heavyweight objects like:

```
JPanel foreground = new JPanel();
Panel frame = new Panel();
Cavas canvas = new Cavas();
foreground.add(frame);
frame.add(canvas);
```

Heavyweight objects might be AWT, or SWT (with OLE), or mixed, it does not matter.

Then get JScrollPane and add AdjustmentListener which calls method like:

```
private void updateLocation() {
    final JScrollPane scroll = getScrollPane();
    if (null == scroll) {
        // do nothing
        return;
    }
    final Point top = getLocation();
    final Rectangle visible = getVisibleRect();

    // set up new location
    frame.setSize(visible.width, visible.height);
    frame.setLocation(visible.x - top.x, visible.y - top.y);
    canvas.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    canvas.setLocation(top.x - visible.x, top.y - visible.y);
}
```